# Bonus continent troops in Risk

Tags: risk

So I have taken over all of Australia and I get 2 extra troops.

My friend then attacks Indonesia from Southeast Asia. When it's my turn I retake control of Indonesia.  Now, do I get 2 more bonus troops since I retook control over the continent?

Answer (score 10):

You gain bonus troops at the start of your turn for controlling an entire continent so as long as you still control Eastern Australia, Indonesia, New Guinea and Western Australia at the start of your next turn you will get the two bonus troops. It doesn't matter if you lose and regain control of all area's in a continent but if you have that control at the start of your turn.

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer to your question is 'no', but it all **depends on the timeline** which you haven't clearly explained.

**At the beginning of your turn** you calculate the bonus armies you receive. In addition to bonus armies for the number of territories you occupy, you receive bonus armies for any complete continents you control. Because this is calculated at the start of your turn, this means you must control these territories for an entire round in order to receive the bonus armies.

Here is the relevant excerpt from the rules:

> **Continents.** In addition, at the beginning of your turn you will
>   receive armies for each continent you control. (To control a
>   continent, you must occupy all its territories at the start of your
>   turn.) To find the exact number of armies you’ll receive for each
>   continent, look at the chart in the lower left-hand corner of the game
>   board.

So, if you lose Indonesia, then when your turn comes around you no longer control Australia and therefore do not receive bonus armies. If, on that turn, you reclaim Indonesia, you still do not receive bonus armies because that bonus is awarded only at the start of your turn. However, if you hold all of Australia through the next round and still control it at the start of your next turn, **then** you will receive your bonus armies for Australia.

The only question to ask is "Do I control it at the start of my turn?"